# was not declared in this scope errors

Tags: c++

I want this program to compute gross salary, but it's outputting errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    float base-salary = 1500.00;
    float bonus-rate = 200.00;
    float commission-rate = quantity * 2/100;
    int quantity;
    float Price;
    float Gross-salary;

    printf("Enter quantity of computers sold\n");
    scanf("%d",&quantity);
    printf("Enter Price of computers sold\n");
    scanf("%f",&Price);

    Gross-salary = base-salary + (quantity * bonus-rate) + (quantity * Price) * commission-rate;
    printf("Gross salary equals :%f",Gross-salary);


    //Gross salary = base salary + (quantity * bonus rate) + (quantity * Price) * commission rate


}
```

**It spits out these errors.**

> 5 13 Documents\Untitled10.cpp [Error] expected initializer before '-'
>   token
>       16    2  Documents\Untitled10.cpp [Error] 'Gross' was not declared in this scope    16    2  Documents\Untitled10.cpp [Error] 'base' was not
>   declared in this scope    16  2  Documents\Untitled10.cpp [Error]
>   'salary' was not declared in this scope   16  2 
>   Documents\Untitled10.cpp  [Error] 'bonus' was not declared in this
>   scope  16 2  Documents\Untitled10.cpp [Error] 'rate' was not declared
>   in this scope 16  2  Documents\Untitled10.cpp [Error] 'commission' was
>   not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `-` dash in C++ identifier names. Switch to underscore.

To quote http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers:

> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of digits, underscores, lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and most Unicode characters (disallowed are control characters and characters in the basic source character set). A valid identifier must begin with a non-digit character (Latin letter, underscore, or Unicode non-digit character). Identifiers are case-sensitive (lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct), and every character is significant.

Besides, use the floating division, not integer, in your calculations.

```
float commission-rate = quantity * 2/100;
```

Since quantity is `int`, integer division will be performed, and you will only get the truncated part of the result. Do so:

```
float commission_rate = quantity * 2/100.f;
```

You have another error with using a variable before declaring it:

```
float commission_rate = quantity * 2/100;
int quantity;
```

Quantity is undeclared so can't be used in line 1. Swap these statements. Also, note that C++ is *not* a symbolic math language. Variable values are taken at the moment when an expression is evaluated. This is a common beginner mistake to first declare a formula, then initialize the variables it contains. Thus, line 1 must be moved below the input section.

Your fixed code might look like this:

```
const float base_salary = 1500.f;
const float bonus_rate = 200.f;
int quantity;
float price;
float gross_salary;

printf("Enter quantity of computers sold\n");
scanf("%d",&quantity);
printf("Enter Price of computers sold\n");
scanf("%f",&price);

const float commission_rate = quantity * 2/100.f;
const gross_salary = base_salary + quantity * bonus_rate + \
                     quantity * price * commission_rate;
printf("Gross salary equals :%f",gross_salary);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the minus sign (-) in variable name declarations.
Use either underscore notation

`float base_salary = 100;` or camelCase (which I prefer):
`float baseSalary = 100;`

Comment: Preferred depends on the style of the project you join, at home you can use anything as long as it's consistent and productive for you.

Comment: Preference for "underscore notation" or camelCase is a stylistic concern, not a technical one - and people differ in their preferences.

Comment: Thanks I've meant preference from my point of view, I'll edit this.